# Get top record on daily basis

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have archive table 
tbl_student_score

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_student_score_archive` (
  `date_archive` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `student_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_archive`,`student_id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO tbl_student_score_archive (date_archive, student_id, score) VALUES 
('2015-03-01', 1, 110),
('2015-03-01', 2, 110),
('2015-03-01', 3, 110),
('2015-03-02', 1, 105),
('2015-03-02', 2, 110),
('2015-03-03', 2, 110),
('2015-03-03', 4, 110),
('2015-03-04', 2, 110),
('2015-03-04', 3, 156),
('2015-03-05', 4, 110)
```

The data is daily basis and only having score different compare to yesterday will be inserted here.

My Question;
How to get top data for all student if I search exspecifically based on the date;

```
select * from tbl_student_score_archive where date_archive='2015-03-04';
```

It should return all student with latest score even though no data for the student on that date;

```
2015-03-04  1   105
2015-03-04  2   110
2015-03-04  3   156
2015-03-04  4   110
```

Comment: Try this `select unique(student_id),date_archive,score from (select * from tbl_student_score_archive order by date_archive) temp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the common [select top N from group](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) problem. Here's one solution:

```
SELECT t1.student_id, t1.score
  FROM tbl_student_score_archive t1
  JOIN (
          SELECT student_id, MAX(date_archive) AS date_archive
            FROM tbl_student_score_archive
           WHERE date_archive <= '2015-03-04'
        GROUP BY student_id
       ) t2
    ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id AND t1.date_archive = t2.date_archive;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1017/14/0)

Comment: That sql does not display all student id if i put 
AND t1.date_archive<='2015-03-04'

Comment: @JoeIjam Oops, I missed that. Updated.

Comment: I love this answer. TQ for helping me!

Comment: I Just wonder, What happend if one day there are so many data up to 10K records. Does it will effect performance very bad?

Comment: @JoeIjam 10k rows sounds like a very manageable amount, especially with your indexes. Of course, ultimately it depends on your environment.